# Problem in if statement comparing GameObject name

Tags: c#, unity

I am trying to get the name of the game object. for that i used

```
    Debug.Log (gameObject.transform.ToString());
```

in start. My gameObject name is "PowerupItem_0" and "PowerupItem_1". in console it displayed the gameObject name correctly. then i tried to execute the statement. so i used

```
    if (gameObject.transform.ToString () == "PowerupItem_0") {
        Debug.Log ("PI_0");
    } else if (gameObject.transform.ToString () == "PowerupItem_1") {
        Debug.Log ("PI_1");
    } else
        Debug.Log ("Oth");
```

for this coding in console it displayed a message as "oth". i am not understanding why its not printing "PI_0" and  "PI_1". anybody please help

[image: Hierarchy tab]
[image: Debug.Log Console]
[image: If Statement Console]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gameObject.transform.ToString()` gives you with `transform` type. Means `(UnityEngine.Transform)` is also included in `string`. You can get `GameObject's` name simply by calling `gameObject.name`.

Answer (score 0):

Like Hamza Hasan said the `(UnityEngine.Transform)` is also a part of the returned string.
Of course you could get the name of the GameObject with `gameObject.name`, but why don't you create a "Powerup_Item" class with a property "Name"?
That would be the better solution in my opinion.

Comment: Your suggestion is right though, but it is irrelevant to the question. He asked why the if check is not working although it returns the name